# How to numerically solve an equation (translate code from Matlab to Python)

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, sympy

I can't find any equivalent of the Matlab function [vpasolve](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.vpasolve.html), which numerically solves an equation. The following is my attempt

Python:

```
alfa = sympy.Symbol('alfa')
y = np.linspace(0, 100, 6)
angleR = np.zeros((1, np.size(y)))

i = 1

for x in range(0, 100, 20):
    p = x/100
    angleR[0, i] = np.rad2deg((sympy.solve(2*np.pi*(1-p) == np.sin(2*alfa), alfa)).astype(float))
    i = i + 1
print(angleR)
```

Which produces the following error

```
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Mul which has no callable sin method
```

Original Matlab code:

```
syms alfa
y = 0:20:100;
angleR = zeros(1, length(y));
i = 1;
for j = 0:20:100
  p = j/100;
  angleR(i) = rad2deg(double(vpasolve(2*pi*(1-p) == 2*alfa - sin(2*alfa), alfa)));
  i = i+1
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues:

- You're mixing sympy and numpy. Numpy deals with numerical inputs, so `np.sin` tries to evaluate `2*alfa` and you get the error you mention. For a symbolic expression you need to use `sympy.sin` instead.
- Fixing that would reveal that `==` in python is used for object equality (boolean value) and has nothing to do with symbolic equality. For the latter you need `sympy.Eq(lhs, rhs)`.
- But that is irrelevant, because to solve an equation numerically you need [`sympy.nsolve`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html#sympy.solvers.solvers.nsolve), with the usage `sympy.nsolve(lhs-rhs, variable, initial_guess)`.

All in all, the following code produces the same result as Matlab. Some minor liberties were taken, i.e. putting the result in a 1D array instead of a "column vector", which is actually a 2D array. But the spirit of the solution is there and you can modify the result format easily.

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym

alfa = sym.Symbol('alfa')
p_values = np.arange(0, 101, 20) / 100
angleR = [
    np.rad2deg(float(sym.nsolve(2*np.pi*(1-p) - 2*alfa + sym.sin(2*alfa), alfa, 0)))
    for p in p_values
]
angleR = np.array(angleR)
```